# How to compile a py file to .so for Autodesk Maya OSX

Tags: python, macos, cython, maya, autodesk

I need to convert a python file to .so (OSX), and  run this module with *Autodesk Maya 2020*. I did this using Cython,I converted the .py file successfully, but when I imported the module to Maya Maya's Python dont recognize the module's functions.

I Dont know much about *Cython* and what type of information I needed to take into account to compile it.

Maya Python: Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 29 2018, 20:59:26)[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin

Current Python: Python 2.7.16 (default, Jan 26 2020, 23:50:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin

Cython Files:
compile.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
ext_modules = [
   Extension("test",  ["test.py"])]
setup(
   name = 'test',
   cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
   ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

test.py

```
import pymel.core as pm
def do():
   mesh=pm.ls(typ= "mesh")
   print mesh
   return mesh
```

main.py

```
import test
test.do()
```

Bash Command :

```
python compile.py build_ext --inplace
```

I get the .so file but when I try to import main.py inside Maya, the function do()  is not found,

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe post the output of your `.so` with `ldd`... `ldd test.do`

Comment: There's (sometimes) a built-in Python module called `test`. It's very easy to end up using that instead of your Cython module. The first thing I'd try is renaming your Cython module to something else.

Comment: You can check, which `test`-module is used via `import test; print test.__file__`

Comment: @ead do you think it's worth someone creating a good simple duplicate target for the `import test` problem? It comes up surprisingly often and there isn't a good target (e.g. this question is very tied to Autodesk so probably isn't a good target)

Comment: @DavidW it is probably a good idea (I hope you will do it:)). However, it is unclear why the `test` from `lib` is picked up: if it is built with `--inplace` and as `.` is in `sys.path` usually before  `lib`,  this should not happen.

Comment: I'll have a look when I have time, see if I can work out the circumstances where it happens (since as you say, it shouldn't really happen)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys seems that changing the name of test worked, I didnt thought that name could cause an issue, thanks a lot to all that awnser mw